# Custom Tabs Within Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a tabs module within (eventually) another tabs module: right now I have the separate just for testing. Everything works find except the first instance of adding class active to the first element of each ui > li > a.

The html is as follows:

```
{{!-- Outer Tabs --}}
<div class="container ">
    <div class="organism video-tabs">
        <div id="parent-tabs">
            <ul class=" tabs parent-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Warranty Requests
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Low Maintenance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a "How To"  href="#">Low Maintenance</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="innercontent">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="innercontent">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="innercontent">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{{!-- End Outer Tabs --}}

<div class="container">
    {{!-- Start Tabs --}}
    <div class="organism video-tabs">
        {{!-- Start Tab Nav --}}
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#"> HVAC Systems</a>
                <div class="arrow"> <img src="/wp-content/themes/atom-child/assets/build/images/triangle.svg">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Plumbing Systems</a>
                <div class="arrow"> <img src="/wp-content/themes/atom-child/assets/build/images/triangle.svg">
                </div>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Electrical Systems</a>
                <div class="arrow"> <img src="/wp-content/themes/atom-child/assets/build/images/triangle.svg">
                </div>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> General Home</a>
                <div class="arrow"> <img src="/wp-content/themes/atom-child/assets/build/images/triangle.svg">
                </div>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Future Video Sets</a>

                <div class="arrow"> <img src="/wp-content/themes/atom-child/assets/build/images/triangle.svg">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {{!-- End Tab Nav --}}
        {{!-- Start Tab Content --}}
        <div class="tab-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/122375452?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320"
                        height="178" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/122375452?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320"
                        height="178" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/122375452?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320"
                        height="178" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">2Some content
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sed mollitia enim omnis nam
                    velit, harum distinctio ab, ipsam obcaecati ad numquam eius totam rerum consequuntur maiores
                    dicta similique? Vero!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">3Some content
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere explicabo nulla impedit nostrum
                    nisi! Fugit porro minus, ex id quod tempore culpa necessitatibus! In perspiciatis consequuntur
                    blanditiis atque. Ipsam, error?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">4Some content
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla minus eos eligendi, eveniet
                    officia voluptatibus corporis excepturi tempore voluptatum? Doloribus obcaecati adipisci harum
                    quam autem quaerat necessitatibus laboriosam reiciendis veniam.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">5Some content
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aperiam quos, aspernatur delectus
                    facilis animi labore minima sequi quo dolores at nostrum unde velit sapiente incidunt nesciunt
                    in explicabo enim? Dolor?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{!-- End Tab Content --}}
    </div>
    {{!-- End Tabs --}}
</div>
```

And here is the js

```
$('.video-tabs').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $containers = $this.find('.tab-content-wrapper .container');
    $(".tabs li a").first().addClass('active');
    $(".tabs .arrow").hide();
    $(".tabs .arrow").first().show();

    $this.find(".tabs li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.find('.arrow').hide();
    $(this).next(".arrow").show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var t = $(this).attr("id");
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    //this is the start of our condition
    $containers.hide();
    $containers.eq(index).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

It all works fine (adding/removing "active" class) once you start clicking around, however in the first load, it's only adding the active class to the first tab set and not the second. Any tips are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I know your mind, your issue is Content Tab in each tab show at the same time, and you want show First Content Tab at First Load. If it's right, just add:

```
$containers.hide();
$containers.first().show();
```

At that time, your code look like:

```
$('.video-tabs').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $containers = $this.find('.tab-content-wrapper .container');
    $this.find(".tabs li a").first().addClass('active');//Change here
    
    $(".tabs .arrow").hide();
    $(".tabs .arrow").first().show();

    //Add here
    $containers.hide();
    $containers.first().show();
    $this.find(".tabs li a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $this.find('.arrow').hide();
      $(this).next(".arrow").show();
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var t = $(this).attr("id");
      var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
      //this is the start of our condition
      $containers.hide();
      $containers.eq(index).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response @phong. The content show ups, just that the first tab doesn't have the active class applied to it. You can see here https://share.getcloudapp.com/NQur6GoX that the first tab has active class but not the second row first tab

Comment: Edited in my answer. How about that?